# Filling Sql table with a script

Tags: python, mysql, shell, tcsh

I have a SQL database and I want to fill tables with a script. The following source code shows what I have done so far:

```
  #!/bin/tcsh
   mysql -h dbs1 -D my_devel -u USER --password=XYZ
   insert into my_table ( col_id, type, file, result, signature) values (***,'###','+++','$$$','...');
   exit
```

According that I pass the parameters '*','#','+','$' and '.' via a method defined in python.

But somehow this is not working for me. Can someone tell me why, or suggest an alternative?

Comment: Why not use python to connect to mysql directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

# count-rows.csh

mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -D tpcw -u root <<EOF
select count(*) from $1;
exit
EOF
```

You need to send the commands to execute to the standard input of the `mysql` utility. There are several ways to do that, but using a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) is probably the easiest method.

That said, if your data comes from a Python program, you should look at using a proper [MySQL connector for Python](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/). You should see a definite performance increase, but more importantly you will be able to handle any errors properly.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Martijn's comment, one of the easiest ways to connect to a MySQL database is using [python-mysqldb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html).